# Preverification Failed - J2ME Project

Tags: java-me, preverify

I am working on a J2ME project in Netbeans. I am having a problem in buiding the project. Whenever I ties to build it, it's giving me preverification error. below are the logs.

```
Executable: C:\WTK2.5.2\bin\preverify
Arguments : -classpath "C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\lib\jsr257.jar;C:\J2ME Client     USE\S60CnB\lib\JSR257Ext.jar;C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\mmapi.jar;C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\jsr75.jar;C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\cldcapi11.jar;C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\jsr239.jar;C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\midpapi20.jar;C:\WTK2.5.2\lib\jsr179.jar" -d "C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\ec09b2f6.tmp" -target CLDC1.1 "C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\build\NKTej2.jar"
JAR file creation failed with error 1
The preverified classes if any are in tmp26379. See jar log of errors in C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\ec09b2f6.tmp\jarlog.txt 
Error preferifying, attempting to print C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\ec09b2f6.tmp\jarlog.txt
====C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\ec09b2f6.tmp\jarlog.txt====
java.io.FileNotFoundException: tmp26379\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:148)
at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1147)
Error: No error
jar -cfm "C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\ec09b2f6.tmp\NKTej2.jar" tmp26379\\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF -C tmp26379 . 
C:\J2ME Client USE\S60CnB\build.xml:146: Preverification failed (result=1)
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

please details of your program. Which UI are you using? Have you gone through your program to see their is no bug? Have you successfully embedded the oracle sdk plugins for netbeans?
These are the possible problem. If it persists, reply...
J2me tutorial at http://www.tutorialmasterng.blogspot.com